# Python Bottle how to pass parameter as json

Tags: python, json, wsgi, bottle

I created an api for openerp using bottle

It works well while access using browser

I don't know how to pass it as json parameters

The Problem is

how can i call using api and pass json parameters like

```
http://localhost/api?name=admin&password=admin&submit=Submit
```

Here is my wsgi code app.wsgi

```
import json
import os
import sys
import bottle
from bottle import get, post, run,request,error,route,template,validate,debug
def login():
        import xmlrpclib
        username = request.forms.get('name')
        pwd = request.forms.get('password')
        dbname = 'more'
        sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
        uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)
        if uid:
                return json.dumps({'Success' : 'Login Sucessful'])

def index():
        return '''
        <html>
        <head>
                <title> Portal</title>
        </head>
        <body>Welcome To PORTAL
   <form method="GET" action="/api/links" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Name:<input name="name" type="text"/><br>
   Password:<input name="password" type="password"/><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>'''

def links():
        return '''
        <html>
        <head>
                <title> Portal</title>
        </head>
        <body>
    <a href="/api/advisor">Advisor<br>
   </body>
   </html>'''

application = bottle.default_app()
application.route('/', method="GET", callback=index)
application.route('/', method="POST",callback=login)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`request.forms`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.forms) is used for POST or PUT requests. The form in your code uses GET, not POST, so you should use [`request.query.getall`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.query), which gives you access to "URL arguments".

Comment: i don't know how & where to use query.getall  will you please post an example here

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code (except pep8 changes), only problem I see is method of the form and location, see the fixed version below ...

```
import json
import os
import sys
import bottle
from bottle import get, post, run, validate, request, error, route, template, debug


def login():
    import xmlrpclib
    username = request.forms.get('name')
    pwd = request.forms.get('password')
    dbname = 'more'
    sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
    uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)
    if uid:
        return json.dumps({'Success': 'Login Sucessful'})


def index():
        return '''
        <html>
        <head>
                <title> Portal</title>
        </head>
        <body>Welcome To PORTAL
   <form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Name:<input name="name" type="text"/><br>
   Password:<input name="password" type="password"/><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>'''


def links():
        return '''
        <html>
        <head>
                <title> Portal</title>
        </head>
        <body>
    <a href="/api/advisor">Advisor<br>
   </body>
   </html>'''


application = bottle.default_app()
application.route('/', method="GET", callback=index)
application.route('/', method="POST", callback=login)

application.run()
```